# Laravel 9.* belongsToMany with belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have DB structure:

```
user
    user_id
    
office
    office_id

project
    project_id

role
    role_id

permission
    permission_id
    
role_permission
    role_id
    permission_id
    
office_user
    office_user_id
    office_id
    user_id
    role_id

project_user
    project_user_id
    project_id
    user_id
    role_id
```

And models:

```
User, Project, Office, Role, Permission
```

Which is the right way to access to `Permission` model from `User` model? I tried this, but in `officeUserPermissions()` wrong `role_id` value, like in `projectUserPermissions()`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'project_user', 'user_id');
    }

    public function offices()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Office::class, 'office_user', 'user_id');
    }

    public function officeRole()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'office_user');
    }

    public function projectRole()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'project_user');
    }

    public function officeUserPermissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'role_permission', 'role_id');
    }

    public function projectUserPermissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'role_permission', 'role_id');
    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you have a field called `user_id` in `users` table?

Answer (score 0):

User and Role model have many to many relationships. You can easily access to role. But the relationship between user and permission is a bit more complicated you need to define a custom SQL query or do like this:

```
//role model

public function permissions() { return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class); }

// user model
public function officeUserPermissions()
 { return $this->officeRole->map(function($role)
  { return $role->permissions}) ;
 }
```

Or

```
$user->offlineRole()->with('permissions')
```